# how to make these four ruby code into one line?

Tags: ruby, string

I want to make these four ruby line into one line to change an IP to his network.
such as "10.10.102.123"=>"10.10.102.0/24"

I use the way below,but I hope to find a more clean way better in one line.

```
network = "10.10.102.123"
network = network.split('.')
network[3] = '0/24'
xx  = network.join('.')
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or just `network = "10.10.102.123".sub(/\d+$/, '0/24')`

Comment: it's really more clean

Answer (score 1):

```
network = "10.10.102.123".sub(/\.\d{1,3}$/, '.0/24')
```

Comment: I test it use:   network = "10.10.102.151".sub(/\.\d{1,3}$/, '0/24')
 #it shows "10.10.1020/24"

Comment: network = "10.10.102.123".sub(/\.\d{1,3}$/, '.0/24') is OK  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Though I like Cary's answer if you wanted to just squish your 4 lines that are doing this with an array you can do it with

```
"10.10.102.103".split('.')[0..-2].push('0/24').join('.')
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm really appreciate it that my question can earn so many answers.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime regexp can be slow and just searching for the '.' is faster

```
address = "10.10.102.123"
address[address.rindex('.')..-1] = '.0/24'
p address #=> "10.10.102.0/24"
```